# Login form modal window on document load

Tags: php, html, css, authentication, simplemodal

How do I add a log in/sign up modal window appearing when the page loads?
I want a simple solution. I have looked online and could not make it work.
Something similar to Pinterest log in form. I want everything to be faded behind with dark overlay and Show log in form that will react to user input when they fill in the details.

---

OK I added the modal window and then script that gets rid of the two divs overlay and login form.

I can not do log out now. it says headers already sent on redirect function.
the result is here http://www.bizclub.co.nf

```
   <?php
    ob_start();
    //session_start(); 

    if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    } else {
    $lang = 'geo';
    }

    //require_once('includes/session.php');
    require_once('classes/class.user.php');
    $user = new USER('');

    if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
    {   
        $user_logout->redirect('index.php');

    }
    if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout']=="true")
    {   $user->Logout();
    echo "YOU ARE LOGGED OUT";
        $user->redirect('index.php');
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `$( document ).ready(function() {
   //your modal here
});`

Comment: modal works now but logout does not. Please check the results on http://www.bizclub.co.nf